# Getting error during deployment of android application?

Tags: eclipse

when I am trying to export signed android application lint show me the fatal error and when i check the lint description it shows me a below error.

1st about app_name. "Issue: Checks for incomplete translations where not all strings are translated
Id: MissingTranslation"

and 2nd about duplicate ID "Duplicate id @+id/image, already defined earlier in this layout

Issue: Checks for duplicate ids within a single layout
Id: DuplicateIds

Within a layout, id's should be unique since otherwise findViewById() can return an unexpected view."
how can i fix it? ![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research about it I got a solution for this problem for that you have to stop link checking during deployment. 
By default, it checks lint error but you can ignore it or resolve all lint error to allow you to deploy

For, this you have to go in window > Preferences > Android > lint error Checking.
.and have to just go with ignore all.

Happy coding..!

Comment: I would suggest to just ignore this error, by changing the level of error to Warning or Ignore. Ignore All it's a bit drastic.